# Get Youtube video id from string

Tags: php, string, youtube

I have a string with youtube video ids like,

```
$str="{youtube}5A3PSnEUJWw{/youtube}test1
      {youtube}7zW8-Jgl60{/youtube} hi{youtube}5A3PSnEUJWw{/youtube}....";
```

Here  in `{youtube}5A3PSnEUJWw{/youtube}` ,5A3PSnEUJWw is an id of youtube videos.

I want get this values as an array like,

```
$array[]='5A3PSnEUJWw';
$array[]='7zW8-Jgl60';
$array[]='5A3PSnEUJWw';
```

How to do this,Anyone have an idea?Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a simple regular expression..

```
<?php
$str="{youtube}5A3PSnEUJWw{/youtube}test1{youtube}7zW8-Jgl60{/youtube} hi{youtube}5A3PSnEUJWw{/youtube}";
preg_match_all('/{youtube}(.*?){\/youtube}/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5A3PSnEUJWw
    [1] => 7zW8-Jgl60
    [2] => 5A3PSnEUJWw
)
```

[image]

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, kindly mark it as accepted solution so that others with the same issue get helped.

Comment: @Yuvaraj I will accept,But i can only accept after 4 minut :)